# Stucked on loops

Tags: java, android

I'm a just a beginner to android & java. I'm trying to build an app that will tell you if you win or lose base on the Martingale on gambling.

My concept is, you can set your money, target and the minimum bet.

for example is if I set my current money is 1000, and my target is to get 1100, and the minimum bet is 100, the app will auto run the function for example 10 times and calculate the win rate.

now I'm stucked, on how to ask the app calculate the win rate, I tried the code below, but it's not working.

```
public int winPercentage (){
  int numberWin = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    boolean win = calRate(double currentMoney, double theTarget, double minBet);
    if (win) {
      numberWin = numberWin + 1;
    }
  }
  return numberWin;
}
```

My Full Java Code Here

```
package com.example.android.gambling;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void seeRate(View view) {

    EditText cMoney = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.money);
    double currentMoney = Double.parseDouble(cMoney.getText().toString());

    EditText target = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
    double theTarget = Double.parseDouble(target.getText().toString());

    EditText bet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bet);
    double minBet = Double.parseDouble(bet.getText().toString());

    TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textview.setText("You " + winPercentage());
  }

  public boolean calRate(double currentMoney, double theTarget, double minBet) {
    while (currentMoney > minBet) {
      boolean win = winRate();
      if (win) {
        currentMoney += minBet;
        minBet = minBet;
      }
      else {
        currentMoney -= minBet;
        minBet *= 2;
      }
      if (currentMoney >= theTarget){
        return true;
      }

    }

    return false;
  }

  private boolean winRate() {
    double d = Math.random();
    if (d < 0.5)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }

  public int winPercentage (){
    int numberWin = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      boolean win = calRate(double currentMoney, double theTarget, double minBet);
      if (win){
        numberWin = numberWin + 1;
      }
    }
    return numberWin;
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Now that i amend the code as below, the android studio shows no error, but when i try to emulate it, it can't be opened, keep showing (unfortunately, app has stopped)

```
package com.example.android.gambling;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    EditText cMoney = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.money);
    double currentMoney = Double.parseDouble(cMoney.getText().toString());

    EditText target = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
    double theTarget = Double.parseDouble(target.getText().toString());

    EditText bet = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bet);
    double minBet = Double.parseDouble(bet.getText().toString());

    boolean findRate = calRate(currentMoney, theTarget, minBet);


    public void seeRate(View view) {


        TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textview.setText("You " + winPercentage());



    }

    public boolean calRate(double currentMoney, double theTarget, double minBet) {

        while (currentMoney>minBet){
            boolean win = winRate();
            if (win){
                currentMoney += minBet;
                minBet = minBet;
            }
            else {
                currentMoney -= minBet;
                minBet *= 2;
            }
            if (currentMoney>=theTarget){
                return true;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean winRate() {
        double d = Math.random();
        if (d < 0.5)
        return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public int winPercentage (){
        int numberWin = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<=10; i++){
            boolean win = calRate(currentMoney, theTarget, minBet);
            if (win){
                numberWin = numberWin + 1;
            }

        }
        return numberWin/10*100;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working ? Can you explain ?

Comment: boolean win = calRate(double currentMoney,double theTarget,double minBet); for this sentence, it keep showing expression expected & identifier expected

Comment: Your edit should be a new question.

Comment: First learn how Methods work in Java. You calling that calRate totally wrong. Second in your MainActivity class, android activity don't works like that. Define your findviewbyid in onCreate and call your method on some button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass arguments to the method `'calRate()` when you are calling it. No need to specify the type of the argument. Change the line to

```
boolean win = calRate(double currentMoney,double theTarget,double minBet);
```

to

```
boolean win = calRate(currentMoney, theTarget, minBet);
```

This will work.

**Edit:**

You have to define the variables, `currentMoney`, `theTarget` and `minBet` inside your method. To do so, you have two options.

1. Make them global: Define the variables outside the `seeRate()` method and use them.
2. Pass them as arguments to the `winPercentage()` method.

Define your `winPercentage()` as follows:

```
public int winPercentage (double currentMoney, double theTarget, double minBet) {
  int numberWin = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<=10; i++){
    boolean win = calRate(currentMoney, theTarget, minBet);
    if (win){
      numberWin = numberWin + 1;
    }

  }
  return numberWin;
}
```

Comment: i tried that as well, but is shows, cannot resolve symbol "currentMoney", "theTarget" and "minBet"

Comment: Yes. You must have variables named `currentMoney`, `theTarget` and `minBet`. I can't see you have defined them anywhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks you very much for your comment, now that i try to make them global, and the android studio shows no error, however, it still cant be opened, it keep shoing " unfortunately, app has stopped" what i did wrong in the code?

Comment: Can't be so sure about that error. May be  a totally different one. Can't say anything until I see the error log, or more details. Post it as another question. If you find this answer is helpful, please accept it. Thanks.